# Cannot access route apart from the homepage in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

When i used http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/, it showed me the welcome message but when i tried to access my login page http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/authentication/login  it shows NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

and have used it on http://localhost:8000/authentication/login and it works fine.

Comment: Just try like, `http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/index.php/authentication/login`

Comment: Thanks. it has worked. but will i need to rewrite it when hosting online?

Comment: Hmm yes. we can rewrite in htaccess.

Comment: Can you show me how to rewrite it pls

Comment: Use like `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Just try like,

> http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/index.php/authenti‌​cation/login

Comment: How to remove index.php from http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/index.php/authenti‌​cation/login and still access the url like http://localhost:8081/paymentclone/public/authenti‌​cation/login